# PHP how can i localize date after 2038

Tags: php, date, datetime, localization, year2038

i try to to use localized dates after 2038 with php

strftime use Timestamp so it doesnt work after 2038

DateTime is not localized...

So I try to use IntlDateFormatter with DateTime :

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2040-01-01');
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fr_FR',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
echo $fmt->format($d);    
echo $fmt->getErrorMessage();
```

here what I get : 
datefmt_format: cannot get timestamp: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Actually i guess IntlDateFormatter internally convert date into timestamp...

So how i can localized date beyond 2038 in php ?

Answer (score 2):

we are getting the same problem here.
This issue shows up in 32 bit machines, because the formatter changes the DateTime value to a integer timestamp to process it . Dates outside the epoch (1970) +- maxint will give you an error. 
There are two ways to fix this: 
1 - use a 64bit server.
2 - fix PHP IntlDateFormatter

We are going with 1- here, good luck!

(The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows). Cf : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php )

Comment: Ok so we pray that all machine in 2038 are 64bit ?
Or anybody try to fix PHP IntlDateFormatter ?

Comment: there is some hack I think but I don't know if it is the best solution